# В чем ошибка импорта почт в ispmanager?

Tags: vps, ispmanager, isp

подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем можем быть ошибка, при попытке массового импорта email адресов отображает следующую ошибку: "Поле 'Email' имеет недопустимое значение. Значением должна быть последовательность вида имя_ящика@доменное_имя". На скрине отобразил формат почт

Почта идет в формате exp.exp@exp.exp-exp.ru. Пробовал в разных форматах, но результата не дало, отдает одну и туже ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня был похожий случай, оказался невидимый символ в начале файле, видно через mc например